# Reading Greek text from jdbc / SQL Server 2005 and displaying it with a servlet

Tags: java, sql-server, unicode, servlets, jdbc

Well, the subject says it all but I will explain a little further.

I have a database in MS SQL server 2005 that contains Greek text. I have created a servlet that connects to that database using `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` and receive some data with the following commands:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
Statement sta = con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
```

After that, I want to use `output.println` to display the data to the page. The result is that Greek characters are displayed as question marks (?). I tried changing the encoding charset of the browser, but no luck, so the problem must be to the page. I also tried displaying

```
new String( res.getBytes("text"), "ISO-8859-7");
```

instead of `res.getString("text")`, with different encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16), but still no luck!

What can I do to see the greek characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be at a number of locations. Check them all:

- the database encoding
- the connection encoding
- the response encoding (`response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")`)

Comment: The problem was with the response encoding. Adding the line response.setContentType ("text/html;charset=utf-8"); solved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [response encoding](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletResponse) to `UTF-8`. Since you normally use JSP for displaying data, you can do this by placing the following line at the top of the JSP page:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) for more background information and all the other aspects you'll need to take into account as well for a Java EE webapplication.

Comment: I was using servlets instead of JSP, however the article about unicode was great !